# Unable to render remote video with WebRTC

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, janus-gateway, webrtc-ios

I am being unsuccessful on rendering a remote video using WebRTC. For context I'm using Janus's streaming plugin.

I'm following what I've been reading so far. Whenever `peerConnection(_ peerConnection:, didAdd stream:)` Is called on `RTCPeerConnectionDelegate`, I create a remote renderer and add it to  the first videoTrack of the stream that the delegate provided me like this:

```swift
#if arch(arm64)
let remoteRenderer = RTCMTLVideoView(frame: self.view.frame)
remoteRenderer.videoContentMode = .scaleAspectFill
#else
let remoteRenderer = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame: self.view.frame)
#endif
            
stream.videoTracks.first?.add(remoteRenderer)
self.view.addSubview(remoteRenderer)
```

But the video will not show, only a black screen.

My delegate has also called `peerConnection(_ peerConnection:, didChange newState:)` with a newState of `RTCIceConnectionState.connected` which makes me think the connection is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try attaching the renderer when you receive the event "didStartReceivingOnTransceiver":

```
func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didStartReceivingOn transceiver: RTCRtpTransceiver) {
    switch transceiver.mediaType {
    case .video:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
                self?.remoteVideoTrack = transceiver.receiver.track as? RTCVideoTrack
                if let renderer = self?.delegate?.viewForRemoteVideoTrack(){
                    self?.remoteVideoTrack?.add(renderer)
                }
            }
    default:
        break
    }        
}
```